# Changing Jitsi UI and removing 3 dots button on hosted server

Tags: flutter, jitsi, lib-jitsi-meet

I am new to server side of coding. Somehow looking at tutorials I was able to host Jitsi server on my hosting.

I am using jitsi_meet plugin with flutter. Till now Jitsi works as expected in app. What I need is remove text

> You are the only one in meeting

and also remove 3 dots menu icon. Instead of menu icon I would love to have camera swap icon there.

What I have done is in /etc/jitsi/meet/my-domain.com-config.js is below

```
// - if `toolbarButtons` is undefined, we fallback to enabling all buttons on the UI
toolbarButtons: [
    'camera',
    //'chat',
    //'closedcaptions',
    //'desktop',
    //'download',
    //'embedmeeting',
    //'etherpad',
    //'feedback',
    //'filmstrip',
    //'fullscreen',
    'hangup',
    //'help',
    //'invite',
    //'livestreaming',
    'microphone',
    //'mute-everyone',
    //'mute-video-everyone',
    //'participants-pane',
    //'profile',
    //'raisehand',
    //'recording',
    //'security',
    //'select-background',
    //'settings',
    //'shareaudio',
    //'sharedvideo',
    //'shortcuts',
    //'stats',
    //'tileview',
    'toggle-camera',
    //'videoquality',
    //'__end'
],
```

But it only made changes to website version not on mobile app (I am using flutter pluging jitsi_meet).

Is there anything else I need to do as well? Please help, how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there should be separate code for web and mobile apps. So you should look more into the codes and understand the separation and you will definitely be able to tweak the UI you are wanting. You can also follow threads like [this](https://community.jitsi.org/t/custom-ui-for-jitsi-meet/17074).

For more responses, you can post in jitsi community where there are lots of jitsi enthusiasts who can guide/help you along your journey related to jitsi. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I posted same question in Jitsi community same day, unfortunately, no response so far. https://community.jitsi.org/t/changing-jitsi-ui-and-removing-3-dots-button-on-hosted-server/108591

Comment: in that thread, there are codes for the android "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/tree/master/android" and the handbook for it "https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk". You can directly change from android code by enabling/disabling toolbar or anything after fetching from  "your_conf_domain/config.js" if it is not implemented there. I think you should achieve your goal by just changing some code/instructions that are given in that thread I have given in answer. Please read that thread thoroughly to get a good idea first of how it is loading configs.

Comment: Thanks, I will go through it.